# How to pass to a JS function a variable containing the class of another div and use it to show/hide the corresponding div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have set up this html code to work with:

```
<span  onclick="togfullspace('unord')">nord</span>
<span onclick="togfullspace('ucenter')">centro</span>
</br>
<div id = "level" class="unord">Hello</div>
<div id="level" class="ucenter">Hi</div>
```

Both id and classes have all been set in the css to `display:none;`

In JavaScript I want the function `togfullspace` to show "Hello" when I click on "nord" and "Hi" when I click on "centro" and if one of the `div`s is already visible I want JS to hide it before showing the clicked one. Here's my JS code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).click(function togfullspace(classe) {
        var idclass = '#level.' + classe;

        if (!$('#level').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#level').hide();
        } else {
            if ($(idclass).is(':hidden')) {

                $(idclass).show();

            } else {

                $(idclass).hide();

            }
        }
    });
});
```

If, instead of using the variable `idclass`, I use `"#level.unord"` it works (only for `<div class="unord">`), so I guess there's something wrong in how I'm handling the variables here. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code to clean it up a little, but it works with little modification:

HTML:

```
<span class="clickable">unord</span>
<span class="clickable">ucenter</span>
</br>
<div class="level" id="unord">Hello</div>
<div class="level" id="ucenter">Hi</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
    var id = "#" + $(this).text();
    alert($(id).text());
    $(".level").hide();
    if ($(id).is(':hidden')) {
        $(id).show();
    } else {
        $(id).hide();
    }
});
```

Here's a working example on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yd059n0u/5/).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have an other question: If I wanted to hide the text if I click again on the same <span> how would I do that? From your code it seems to me it should do it automatically, and yet it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML5 [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute), you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

In other words, `$('#level').is(':hidden')` is only checking on the first div.

My suggestion: use a common class to denote levels instead of ids:

```
<div class="level unord">Hello</div>
<div class="level ucenter">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<span data-cor="div1">div 1</span>
<div class="div1">this is div 1</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span').on('click',function(){
    $('.'+$(this).data('cor')).toggleClass('hidden');
    // or use slideToggle instead
});
```

Code has not been tested only for example purpose.

Other option would be to get the element index but therefor both should have same index relative to their parent element. And therefor both in different element.